# Pass JavaScript Value from Webview to Activity?Android

Tags: javascript, android, string, webview

I followed [this](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4601&scat=50&pcat=52) to Print in android (**Thermal Printer**)

This is [My web-view](https://jsfiddle.net/sL1pwp8b/) Over there On-click  It will Load My Android Activity Which is Out of Web-view...

For that I have Given this... to Open new activity from web-view..

```
public class Main_web extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_m);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webm);

    WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Main_web.this, "Please Wait", "Loading...");

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "NewFUN");
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

    {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    String url = "www.google.com/m_app_eta.php";
    //String url = "file:///android_asset/tex.html";
    try {

        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);

        } else {
          //do something
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         //do something

    }

}

//Class to be injected in Web page

public class WebAppInterface {

    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void Print() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave to next screen?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent chnIntent = new Intent(Main_web.this, Print_activity.class);
                        startActivity(chnIntent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
}
```

Now My printer Activity is working Fine So here I want to pass a Value On click  Button Which Opens Printer... But can Any one suggest me How to Receive same value in android Activity not in web-view...

All I need is In my web-view when I click on the Button its loading Android Activity Along with that I want to Pass A string value to new Activity

Why Should I pass Value means In that I have a Url so I can Print with that URL 
Here JS value is different form current URL

**Update**

I followed [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html) But its Inside the Web-view I want same at Outside the web-view...

Means When I click on the web-view Its opening android activity with the same its should pass a value to my activity not the web-view

**Update 1**

I followed @Sujal Mandal answer But I dont Know How to use that Value In next activity Can any one suggest me... on this kind... in next activity It may in `System.out.println` or `text-view` or any other `string` So I can use can Any one suggest How to Use the JavaScript Value in other activity outside the web-view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML JS CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Pa(value) {
       //value is the param received from onClick
       NewFUN.Print(value); //call the android method with value param
    }
</script>

<center>
    <h3>Sample HTML</h3>
    <div id="content">Click on Button To thermal print</div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onClick="Pa('26997')" /><br/>
        </div>
</center>
```

& change your android code to be like this

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void Print(final String stringFromWebView) {
        //use stringFromWebView
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave to next screen?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent chnIntent = new Intent(Main_web.this, Print_activity.class);
                        chnIntent.putExtra("STRING_DATA", stringFromWebView);
                        startActivity(chnIntent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

In next activity receive the web JS response by using

`String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("STRING_DATA");`

at oncreate

Comment: This is fine But its not working... If I give this `public void Print()` Its Opening new Activity... But If I give this public void Print(String stringFromWebView) its not working Because.. I have Given this in JS `function Pa(value) {
       NewFUN.Print();
    }`   SO here what ever its there it will work `NewFUN.Print();` ,NewFUN.Splash();.. but its not working when I give NewFUN.Print(String stringFromWebView);

Comment: Thanks for Responce @Sujal Mandal

Comment: NewFUN.Print('string') try this, why would you pass a variable declaration as a parameter anyway?

Comment: alternatively if you have a variable in js just pass the variable in the method it should work, e.g var valToSend="string stringer"; NewFUN.Print(valToSend);

Comment: Sorry I am not getting SO asked can you update your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137624/discussion-between-dont-be-negative-and-sujal-mandal).

Comment: Thanks @Sujal Mandal Can you suggest me hwo to use to this  `stringFromWebView` in next activity or system.out.print... so that I can use that value to my printer.. please this is final one.. I will accept your answer.. But I dont know how to use that responce in other activty...