# Android Alert with "Don't show again" checkbox in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, checkbox, webview, sharedpreferences

I have a Web-view In that on click with the help JavaScript interface it will open My android activity's from web-view Here its working fine...

So Here When User Click on any button Which is JS-Interface.. I have added a Alert

So when Ever User click on it... It will show a Dialog...

Now I followed [this](https://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/use-alertdialog-with-checkbox-to-handle-dont-show-again/) to add a Option like Don't ask again.... Check box

Here I have given Shared prefs and Check box... But its not working...

and One more thing that check box is viable in web-view... it should show only on alert.. But its showing all time...

Can any one suggest me .. How to Show Alert with Check box.. dont ask again in android Webview... and remember the check box...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Mypackage/myactivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class checkbox
```

**Update**

Here is [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42663484/5010291) for that I have added the [example code](https://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/use-alertdialog-with-checkbox-to-handle-dont-show-again/)... at alert...

Actually I need a Check Box without XML for Checkbox...(Due to XML for Check box my Main Web-view is Getting some errors)
Is it possible.. If so Let me Know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to break down your problem into 2 parts

1) **Display dialog and remember if user have chosen to not show it again**

A simple alert dialog with shared preferences can do that.

```
   private void handleAlertDialog() {
    //Handle showAlert
    //check if allow to show dialog
    if (!getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile1", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("ShowDialog", false)) {

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Would like to Remember this setting ? "};

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebViewActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Allow location access")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            //If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                            // Don't Allow, remember


                            getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile1", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                    .edit()
                                    .putBoolean("ShowDialog", true).commit();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remember", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {


                            getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile1", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                    .edit()
                                    .putBoolean("ShowDialog", false).commit();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Don't Remember", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                        //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                    }
                }).create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

2)  **Trigger this method from javascript.**

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is deprecated after Android N show you need to override  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` as well.

A complete WebViewClient class will look like this.

```
    /**
    * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(WebViewActivity.this);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                //Handle mail Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url)));

            } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {

                //Handle telephony Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));

            } else if (url.startsWith("showalert:")) {
                handleAlertDialog();

            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            if (uri.toString().startsWith("mailto:")) {

                //Handle mail Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri));
            } else if (uri.toString().startsWith("tel:")) {

                //Handle telephony Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri));
            } else if (uri.toString().startsWith("showalert:")) {

                 //Handle Alert
                handleAlertDialog();

            } else {
                //Handle Web Urls
                view.loadUrl(uri.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;

            if (loadingDialog == null || !loadingDialog.isShowing())
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "",
                        "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        });

            loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                    WebResourceError error) {


            if (isConnected()) {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "onReceivedError : " + error.getDescription(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            } else {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            }

            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view,
                                        WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

            if (isConnected()) {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "HttpError : " + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            } else {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            }
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {

                if (null != loadingDialog) {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    loadingDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`isConnected` method is used to check network connection

```
/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity
 *
 * @return is Device Connected
 */
public boolean isConnected() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (null != cm) {
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    return false;

}
```

As you can see I have added a filter to check for URL start with `showalert:`. If my Web client class catches any URL starting with `showalert` then it triggers `handleAlert` method.

**Result**

[image]

2)  **Trigger this method from javascript.**

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is deprecated after Android N show you need to override  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` as well.

A complete WebViewClient class will look like this.

```
    /**
    * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(WebViewActivity.this);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                //Handle mail Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url)));

            } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {

                //Handle telephony Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));

            } else if (url.startsWith("showalert:")) {
                handleAlertDialog();

            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            if (uri.toString().startsWith("mailto:")) {

                //Handle mail Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri));
            } else if (uri.toString().startsWith("tel:")) {

                //Handle telephony Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri));
            } else if (uri.toString().startsWith("showalert:")) {

                 //Handle Alert
                handleAlertDialog();

            } else {
                //Handle Web Urls
                view.loadUrl(uri.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;

            if (loadingDialog == null || !loadingDialog.isShowing())
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "",
                        "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        });

            loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                    WebResourceError error) {


            if (isConnected()) {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "onReceivedError : " + error.getDescription(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            } else {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            }

            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view,
                                        WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

            if (isConnected()) {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "HttpError : " + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            } else {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            }
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {

                if (null != loadingDialog) {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    loadingDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`isConnected` method is used to check network connection

```
/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity
 *
 * @return is Device Connected
 */
public boolean isConnected() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (null != cm) {
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    return false;

}
```

As you can see I have added a filter to check for URL start with `showalert:`. If my Web client class catches any URL starting with `showalert` then it triggers `handleAlert` method.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HiteshSahu sir, Here I am using `SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);` instead of `PreferenceManager` can you please update your answer with my shared prefs name because I have given this to some of the activities in a different  way actually it need to save file in `MyPrefsFile1.xml` in saredprefs but now its saving as my.example.webv_prefernce.xml please help me on this...   your answer is working but I need to assign the same value to diff options.. so I have added like if its false open activity with alert else open activity.. but need shared prefs file